# Is there any way to check if this is working fine

Tags: cdn

We have subscribed for CDN (content delivery network) for our website.

Is there any way to (any online tool to display) see the server locations available.

Is there any way to check if this is working fine?

Answer (score 0):

I used http://web-sniffer.net/

Look at the Response header for Server. Previously mine was Apache/2.2.22, after setting up cloudflare it was still Apache/2.2.22, but using web sniffer it showed it as cloudflare-nginx.

previously I'd been looking at response headers in chrome dev tools, but web sniffer gave different server response headers ?!

Comment: @S: response headers in chrome dev tools might follow server's redirect commands and thus show you the HTTP headers of the final destination server. The online web sniffers are normally not following the redirect command and as a result give you a more accurate information on server response headers. BTW, the linked web-sniffer net site frequently fails for some reason, I would recommend to use http://websniffer.cc/ which works similarly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like this https://is-it.online/ to measure page/resource load times at various places on the globe. If the CDN setup up is really working it should consistently show  similar response times from all the locations, if not it will be lesser at the location closer to where the site is physically hosted and will increase as you go physically away from it.

Full guide is here : https://medium.com/@abhijeeta/how-to-check-if-cdn-is-working-for-my-website-9fa96cd6ba32

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the CDN has improved the page loading speed for your visitors worldwide, you can use performance testing tools like [pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/) or [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/) and select different locations to test the load time. However, for each location, you will need to run the test twice as during the first run the CDN is expected to take longer than the usual because it has to fetch those files at that geography first before delivery.

If you want to check the number of locations of a CDN, you can get an idea of it with tools like [CDN Latency Benchmark](https://www.cdnperf.com/tools/cdn-latency-benchmark). This gives you the latency of the CDN at the world level, plus gives you the list of IPs the CDN resolves to in different countries.